# SQL Procedure: Generating random password and storing it in database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

What I want to do is to create a random password and save the hashed password to db.

I am using the "random password create procedure" from [this site.](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2534/sql-server-stored-procedure-to-generate-random-passwords/)
And here is how I save the hashed version of it to the datbase.

```
declare @salt varbinary(4) = CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4);
declare @hash varbinary(max); 

//random generated password gets set in @output

set @hash = 0x0200 + @salt + HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', CAST(@output AS VARBINARY(MAX)) + @salt)
update DBtable SET PwHash = @hash,PwSalt= @salt WHERE Id=1
```

What I am wondering is if I should save the salt to the database at all? Since when I am testing this it seems to be working to verify the password with a random generated salt. Is this intended?

Testing method.

```
declare @pswd1 nvarchar(max) = '_CWgDb2g'; 
declare @salt1 varbinary(4) = CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4);
declare @salt2 varbinary(4) = 0x6BE9FF69;
declare @hash1 varbinary(max); 
declare @hash2 varbinary(max); 
set @hash1 = 0x0200 + @salt1 + Hashbytes('SHA2_512', Cast(@pswd1 As varbinary(max)) + @salt1);
set @hash2 = 0x0200 + @salt2 + HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', Cast(@pswd1 AS varbinary(max)) + @salt2);
```

And if I just run

```
Select 
Compare1 = PWDCOMPARE('_CWgDb2g',@hash1),
Compare2 = PWDCOMPARE('_CWgDb2g',@hash2)
```

Both returns 1. So is something wrong? Or doesn't the salt matter?
@salt2 is what the generate method returns.

Comment: IMHO if the salt does not matter, then something is wrong in the encryption process.

Comment: Yea, that's what I thought aswell :P I took the encryption method from here: http://sqlity.net/en/2460/sql-password-hash/

Comment: One old technique is to use the username for the account as, or to generate, the salt. It makes dictionary attacks much harder since you need to build one for each username, but it doesn't require storing any additional data.

Comment: But CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4); generates a random salt. The problem is that it doesn't seem like it matters in the verify process. Since as shown I can just use a random salt to verify the password so then it have to be something wrong somewhere??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, by generating your hash using this PWDENCRYPT method, your salt is already stored in the db. If you look at the formula to create the hash1 value, the plain salt value is included in "plaintext" within the hash1 value itself, outside of the actual HASHBYTES call.

```
set @hash1 = 0x0200 + @salt1 + Hashbytes('SHA2_512', Cast(@pswd1 As varbinary(max)) + @salt1);
```

PWDCOMPARE knows how to take the salt into consideration when performing the comparison, which is why it doesn't matter what salt value is used. Somewhere in PWDCOMPARE, it knows to take the salt from that particular location within the hash, combine it with the password, and perform the hash to get the same result.

Comment: Ok. So should I change anything in my methods? No need to store the salt then atleast.

Comment: Yup, no need to store the salt in your table; you can just store the hash.